# if last element echo'class="last"'

Tags: php

I am new to php and I am trying to create a simple bit of code that prints a "last" class at the start of the last element in a "while" loop. There are only two items in the loop (blog excerpts) hence why I have tried below with the if ($i == 1)... Thanks for any help.

Here is my code so far - which only returns the p

```
   <?php
     $i = 0;
     if($i == 1) {
      echo '<p class="last">';
     }
     else {
      echo '<p>';
     }
   ?>
```

EDIT:

Thanks for the help so far. Greatly appreciated - I have provided a bit more information below (I posted late at night, so I realise I haven't been all that clear).

This is the full piece of code I am trying to write. It is pulling blog excerpts from Wordpress - currently limited to 2 blog articles.

```
<?php 
 $posts = new WP_Query('showposts=2');
 while ( $posts->have_posts() ) : $posts->the_post(); 
?>
 <p><a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>"><?php echo the_title(); ?></a><br/>
    <?php echo substr(get_the_excerpt(), 0,200); ?>... <a href="<?php echo get_permalink();   ?>">Read More</a></p>
<?php endwhile; ?> 
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

I am wanting to add the class "last" to the p at the start of line 5 - for the last blog except only.

Thanks again.

Comment: You're setting `$i` immediately before you test it. `$i` will always equal 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you have two paragraphs, and you want to apply the class "last" to the last one?  Sounds like this is better handled with CSS

```
<style>
  #contents p:last-child {
     PUT CONTENTS OF CLASS HERE
  }
</style>
<body>
  <div id="#contents">
    <p> first info</p>
    <p> last info </p>
  </div>
</body>
```

OR if you want to learn about loops

```
<?php
  $numLoops = 2;
  for($i=0; $i<$numLoops; $i++) {
    if($i == (numLoops-1)) {
        echo '<p class="last">';
     } else {
        echo '<p>';
     }
  }
```

What we are doing here with the for loop is initially setting the variable $i=0; then setting a test that says keep looping as long as the variable is less than the number of loops we want do do.  Next we are setting what to do each loop, in this case we increment our variable by one each time.

First loop

```
i=0, we see that 0 is < 2 so we continue
```

Second loop

```
We execute the $i++ so we increment $i by 1 from 0 to $i=1, 
we test and see $i=1 is still less than 2 so we continue.
```

Third attempted loop

```
We increment $i by 1 and get $i=2.  
We test to see if this is less than 2, but it is NOT so we do not execute code in the loop
```

The main issue is that you don't have a loop in your code, and if you did you aren't incrementing your variable $i

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have added some more information to my original post, as I realise that I didn't give enough information (posting late at night when tired didn't help). Any further assistance will be greatly appreciated. Thanks again.

Comment: The CSS solution still works, and is the way you want to go.  Just enclose the paragrphs in a div with the ID of contents, or change the css line from #contents p:last-child to body p:last-child and it'll apply to the last <p> i entire page

Comment: Nick - you're a start. Who would have thought it was so easy. Thanks again! I'll take away your code above for future reference too.

Answer (score 1):

Nick's answer says almost all that needs to be said.
The only thing I might add is a slight variation to save duplication particularly if the  the contents of your paragraph tags is more complicated.

This might be better done with the following tweak on Nick's code:

```
<style>
  #contents p:last-child {
     PUT CONTENTS OF CLASS HERE
  }
</style>
<body>
  <div id="#contents">
<?php
  $numLoops = 2;
  $ctext=""
  for($i=0; $i<$numLoops; $i++) {
    $info="whatever";
    if($i == (numLoops-1)) {
        $ctext=' class="last"';
    }
    echo "<p${ctext}>${info}</p>\n";
  }
?>
  </div>
</body>
```

Cheers

Comment: Thanks for the help. I have provided a bit more information in my original post. What you have posted here looks like it might achieve what I want, with some tweaking. Any help on getting there would be greatly appreciated :D But thanks anyway.